# Getting data from database using stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am designing a web application. I have created and tables and columns. I was trying to insert user details using asp.net. But not displaying user details in SQL Server and happy thing is no errors. Can anyone suggest me what would be the reason for this?

This is the code for `btnSave__Click`:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) HandlesbtnSave.Click
    Dim recepient As String = CheckChanges()
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection

    cn.ConnectionString = conStrDRS

    Using cn
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UpdateRegistration", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CounterParty", txtCounterParty.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Custodian", ddlCustodian.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.ParseExact(YourDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerDepartment", ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", getUserName(hUserID.Value, "name"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", txtRemarks.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue)
```

cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        cn.Close()
    End Sub

And this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateRegistration]
   (@Title nvarchar(500),
    @CounterParty nvarchar(200),
    @Company nvarchar(10),
    @Custodian varchar(25),
    @OwnerDepartment  varchar(100),
    @Remarks nvarchar(1000),
    @Status varchar(2),
    @SecurityLevel varchar(2),
    @CreatedBy varchar(25),
    @CreatedOn datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Registration(Title, Counterparty, Company,
                                 Custodian, OwnerDepartment, Remarks,
                                 Status, SecurityLevel, CreatedBy, CreatedOn)
    VALUES (@Title, @Counterparty, @Company,
            @Custodian, @OwnerDepartment, @Remarks,
            @Status, @SecurityLevel, @CreatedBy, @CreatedOn)
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u have to do `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to execute the procedure

Comment: You aren't ever executing your `SqlCommand`. . .

Comment: Thanks for your answers now I am getting errors with Createdon and CreatedBy

Comment: After adding sql command I am getting this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'UpdateRegistration' expects parameter '@CreatedBy', which was not supplied

Comment: `@ReferenceNo` is not in your proc but you're passing it via code !!. You've 10 args in proc and passing 11 args via code

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the Sql command

You are missing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) HandlesbtnSave.Click
        Dim recepient As String = CheckChanges()
         Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = conStrDRS
        Using cn
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UpdateRegistration", cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNo", txtReferenceNo.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CounterParty", txtCounterParty.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Custodian", ddlCustodian.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.ParseExact(YourDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerDepartment", ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue)

   string user = getUserName(hUserID.Value, "name");
   user == null ? cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy",DBNull.Value):
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy",user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", txtRemarks.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Execute the stored procedure
        End Using
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: @avi that means now data is passing.. can you check the value is coming after parseexact and getUserName()

Comment: After adding sql command I am getting this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'UpdateRegistration' expects parameter '@CreatedBy', which was not supplied.

Comment: @avi can u post the procedure signature?

Comment: what `getUserName(hUserID.Value, "name")` is returning? i think it is returning null for @CreatedBy

Comment: @avi thats why it is giving error..then in procedure you should wrote that parameter to accept null `,@CreatedBy  varchar(25) = NULL` else u should check in C# code that is it null and do the needful

Comment: @avi check my modfied answer]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` as well as you are passing one extra parameter which is not existing in stored procedure

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNo", txtReferenceNo.Text)
```

so the such like :

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) HandlesbtnSave.Click
  Dim recepient As String = CheckChanges()
  Dim cn As New SqlConnection
  cn.ConnectionString = conStrDRS

  Using cn
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UpdateRegistration", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CounterParty", txtCounterParty.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", ddlCompany.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Custodian", ddlCustodian.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.ParseExact(YourDate,
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss KKKK yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerDepartment", ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", getUserName(hUserID.Value, "name"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", txtRemarks.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel",
    ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  End Using
  cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But what does this error mean....System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'UpdateRegistration' expects parameter '@CreatedBy', which was not supplied.

Comment: hi, will you please check this function ' getUserName(hUserID.Value, "name") ' is returning some value or not.

Comment: is it returning null value ?

Comment: yes no value ....Is the code correct or any modification in coding???
Is this error mean  code error ????   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'UpdateRegistration' expects parameter '@CreatedBy', which was not supplied

Comment: Try this modification in store procedure :                                                 ' @CreatedBy varchar(25) = NULL '.                                                 Actually we are passing no value in CreatedBy but we define CreatedBy in store procedure is not null-able. so when we passing no value error will occur. if you want to pass no value in CreatedBy parameter of store procedure you need to define the default value of that parameter.

Comment: Done as u said got the error that you cannot make the @createdby as NULL

Comment: check your table in database. there column in CreatedBy is not null-able check the check box of null-able in table.

Comment: In table it is not null.... cannot check box now has to delete and want to create are you sure if we make it as null will it execute....

Comment: wait will you please write here table structure.

Comment: make CreatedOn NULL and check. and no need to create the table again just modify in the same.